# Calling Object Constructor from within itself

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to javascript object and in my ongoing project i am facign a problem where i have to recall the object constructor from inside for example

```
function MediaRule(name, parent, string) {
this.name = name;
this.parent = parent;
this.rules = new Array();

while(string != "") {

    if (string.charAt(0) == '@') {
        if (string.search("@keyframes") == 0) {

        }
        else {
            mediaString = new String;
            var endString = false;
            var nestLevel = 0;
            while (endString == false) {
                var brace = string.indexOf("}");
                var getString = string.substring(0,brace+1).trim();
                mediaString += getString;
                string = string.replace(getString, "").trim();
                if (string.charAt(0) == "@") {
                    nestLevel++;
                }
                else if (string.charAt(0) == "}") {
                    if (nestLevel > 0) {
                        mediaString += "}";
                        string = string.replaceAt(0, "");
                        nestLevel--;
                    }
                    if ((nestLevel == 0) && (string.charAt(0) == "}")) {
                        mediaString += "}";
                        string = string.replaceAt(0, "");
                        var aIndex = mediaString.indexOf("{");
                        var bIndex = mediaString.lastIndexOf("}");
                        var eleString = mediaString.substring(aIndex+1,bIndex).trim();
                        var mediaQName = mediaString.substring(0, aIndex).trim();
                        this.rules.push(new MediaRule(mediaQname, this.name, eleString))
                        endString = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this object constructor is being called again and again from inside when certain condition is met the problem is that it works if i nest one level but beyond that the browser hangs i think i am doing something wrong with how the constructor is being called. i want this to work no matter how many times the same string pattern is nested.

Comment: one of your problems (besides complicated code structure) might be that `mediaString` is a global property of `window` -> a global variable. Try with `var mediaString`.

Comment: It's OK to call a function from within a function or a constructor from within a constructor as long as it doesn't go on forever.  I'd suggest that you trace your code in a debugger and watch what is happening and discover why it hangs and when it isn't doing what you expect it to.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake when i pasted the code, i am already using var mediaString. @hgoebl

Comment: first of all: please try to restructure your code. I think nobody wants to read and understand it. At the end you should have much less levels of indentation.

Comment: okay sir I'm going to go through my code again. @jfriend00 okay ill do that as well but it's weird that it works the first time but on second level of calling it hangs.